# Error in the scheduler of web2py

Tags: web2py

When I try to create a new model in web2py for scheduller I get an error. The model is as follows

```
`def f():
    a = 2
    return ()
```

`from gluon.scheduler import Scheduler
scheduler = Scheduler(db,dict(our_function=f))`

I get the following error:

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
 exec ccode in environment
 File "/home/www-data/web2py/applications/Home_Lights/models/mtasks.py", line             `42, in <module>`
 Scheduler(db,dict(our_function=f))
 File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/scheduler.py", line 587, in __init__
 self.define_tables(db, migrate=migrate)
 File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/scheduler.py", line 655, in define_tables
 format='%(task_name)s')
 File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 799, in  `define_table`
 raise SyntaxError('table already defined: %s' % tablename)

    SyntaxError: table already defined: scheduler_task`
```

I suspect it has to do with the execution permission of the newly created model. any help is appreciated...?

Answer (score 1):

Just set:

```
migrate=False
```

so it doesn't try to recreate the table

```
from gluon.scheduler import Scheduler
scheduler = Scheduler(db,tasks=dict(our_function=f), migrate=False)
```

Comment: thanks. I had no idea that the migrate setting of the db was not used when making the scheduler tables.